# ubuntu 13.04, python 2.7, alsa audio problems

Tags: 13.04, sound, alsa, python-2.7

I am using Ubuntu 13.04...having ALSA sound problems with Python.

1. using aplay, I can play a *.wav from the command line - works fine
2. other apps using sound card - work fine
3. I am using Python 2.7; I have installed several Python alsa packages....
     but not working for me

Here is what I currently have, regarding ALSA:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep alsa

alsa-base                           install
alsa-utils                  install
bluez-alsa:i386                 install
gnome-alsamixer                 install
gstreamer0.10-alsa:i386             install
gstreamer1.0-alsa:i386              install
python-alsaaudio                        install
python-pyalsa                   install
```

I could send along lots of others info but not sure relevant.

If you could make a few suggestions of things to check, I will get busy...

Not working -> 1) python gives no errors, plays the file, I hear no sound.
               2) from the Desktop, go to Sound, Test -> works fine
               3) from the command line, use aplay + way file, works fine

Conclusion: Python2.7 + Ubuntu + ALSA -> does not work 
                                      -> does not play the WAV sound file correctly
                                      -> I hear nothing

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Have you submitted a ticket to the author? See http://sourceforge.net/p/pyalsaaudio/bugs/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple python2/python3 program to use mpg321 and/or aplay for Raspberry Pi using Whezzy- side note added GUI buttons to start and stop audio

in python
os.system('aplay Song.wav &')

must use & or it does not work not sure why

for mpg321
os.system('mpg321 Song.mp3 &')

Check your master volume if you do not hear anything
from command line amixer cset numid=1 80%  to increase volume